# Bound States in Dirac Delta Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider a particle of mass m in the potential:

$$V(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rll}\infty & \text { for } & x \leq 0 \\ -V_{0} \delta(x-a) & \text { for } & x>0\end{array}\right.$$

where $V_0>0$.

What condition must be satisfied by $a$ for bound states to exist?
How many bound states exist?

I know that the existence of the bound states depends on the size of $a$ but I don't know what the relationship would be specifically.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Fox $x\leq 0$ (left region) the potential barrier is infinite. Then particle cannot tunel to that region, so the wave function of the particle is $0$ for $x\leq 0$. In the right region particle can move freely unless it met a well. It can be Dirac Delta well. So the point $a$ should lie in the rigth region $x>0$.